# How to run specific commands without to press enter key

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

How can I run a specific command in terminal without to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after I typed the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bind`:

```
bind -x '"<command>"':<command>
```

For example `bind -x '"ls"':ls` will make that when you type only `ls` (not followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to show directly the result of `ls` command.

To make the change permanently, you can insert the previous line in `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: This has a lot of drawbacks! you'll never be able to type `ls` anymore. Type `printf '%s\n' {,/usr}/bin/*ls*` for a sample of commands you'll never be able to type again. Not mentioning all the files and options that contain `ls` and that won't be usable anymore. `:(`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You are right partially. Look here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zJOpv.png

Comment: How do you do that then? `l space delete s`? (watch out I edited the `printf` command in my previous comment... I forgot a `/`).